# Error in Java Code

Tags: java

I am a beginner at Programming and would appreciate some help and advice on this java error that I am getting.This is part of a code I am working on but I am getting an error of  "i cannot be resolved" which is on the i's in the System.out.println part of the code.

```
private static void printBill(ArrayList bills) 
{
    //prints out data
    for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++);
    {
        System.out.println("Bill number: " + i + ":" + bills.get(i).toString());
    }       
}
```

I am not understanding this error or how to correct it. I just want it print
Bill number 1: Rent 800 (what ever the user inputs basically)

This is my whole code for this driver class(if it helps to see the whole thing):

```
public class BillsDriver 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many bills do you have? ");
        scanner.nextLine();

        //array of Bills
        ArrayList bills = new ArrayList();


        boolean more = true;

        while(more)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter bill name: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter bill amount: ");
            double amount = sc.nextDouble();

            Bills thisBill = new Bills(name, amount);

            bills.add(thisBill);

            System.out.println("More bills?(true/false)");
            more = sc.nextBoolean();

        }       printBill(bills);


    }

    private static void printBill(ArrayList bills) 
    {
        //prints out data
        for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++);
        {
            System.out.println("Bill number: " + i + ":" +  bills.get(i).toString());
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: How would I go about totaling all the bill amounts? How do you total/sum the arraylist?
If it was 
Bill # 1: Rent 800
Bill # 2: Cable 100

then I would have 
Total Amount due: 900

Comment: override the Bills `toString()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++);
```

Remove it and the error should be gone.

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring at my screen for a minute now. Can't believe it was that simple!

Comment: Could you help point me in the right direction as to adding up all amounts in the arraylist to give a Total Amount due?

Comment: If your bill class has the method `double getAmount()`, you can just add them up by introducing another variable around the for loop, say "double total" and in each iteration do: `total += bills.get(i).getAmount()`. If you'd like more details, please show your bill class.

Comment: public class Bills 
{
 
 private double amount;
 private String name;
 

 public Bills(String name, double amount) 
 {
  
  this.name = name;
  this.amount = amount;
 }
 
 public Bills()
 {
  this("New Expense: ",0);
 }
 
 public String toString()
 {
  return name + "\t" + "\t" +amount;
 }
 
 public double getTotal()
 {
  return amount;
 }


}

Comment: Thank you for showing the code. Something like this should work: `double total = 0; for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++){ total += bills.get(i).getTotal();}`

Comment: Thank you!
I am now having trouble with getting a grandTotal. I want to subtract ArrayList A total - ArrayList B total.

I have tried 
double grandTotal = 0;
grandTotal = totals - total;

Answer (score 5):

You've got an extra semicolon on the end of your for loop in printBill.

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++);
```

remove it

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++);
```

to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("Bill number: " +String.valueOf(i) + ":" + bills.get(i).toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use :

```
public class BillsDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         BillsDriver theBillsDriver = new BillsDriver();
         theBillsDriver.startBillSystem();
    }

    void startBillSystem() {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("How many bills do you have? ");
         scanner.nextLine();
    ...///Rest of code from main
```

Comment: @user29655493 This also means that in future you could pass as a parameter to `startBillSystem` of a previous list to add to what the user is typing in. Maybe from a file or database of previously entered bills.